# How long is the approval process for Officejs add-ins?

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I have submitted my Excel Add-ins (Using OfficeJS) for 10 days, but the status in [the summary page](https://sellerdashboard.microsoft.com/Registration/Summary) still says

> Status: Pending approval
>
> We are verifying your account information.

From your experience, how long would it take for the approval process to go through?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a 3rd party service, not about programming.

Comment: This looks to be an **account** verification message, not a validation related message. Please open a support ticket for assistance in resolving this. 
Step 1: Contact [Support](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=272975)
Step 2: Choose Category as "Seller Dashboard registration and your account".
Step 3: Choose "Registering for a developer account"
Step 4: Choose contact method

Answer (score 1):

This can take 3-5 working days, depending on the volume of submissions in the queue.

You could refer to the following link:

[Make your solutions available in AppSource and within Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-the-office-store)